# Cordova Blank Screen: Android RenderLayerBacking with Composited Bounds of Zero

Tags: android, cordova, rendering, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm running into a strange issue with a Cordova/PhoneGap application on Android JellyBean.  From time to time the screen goes blank when I'm displaying full screen images.  (The problem doesn't occur on other device families.)  During that time the following message gets continuously dumped to the console:

> D/RenderLayerBacking(31717): isDirectlyCompositedImage : layer(480,320) [composited bounds 0,0]

I haven't been able to find any good leads.  Any suggestions on where to look?   Thx!

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs on occasion when you interrupt a transition on Android JellyBean (webkit) by starting another transition before the previous animation has terminated.

This can be resolved by removing the previously set *-webkit-transition-duration* from the object before starting another transition.